# Activity History and Open Activities using REST

Tags: rest, activities

So, I've been trying to implement the below link using REST's Query and QueryAll call;

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_activityhistory.htm

This in turns gives me an output like below;

```
SELECT ( SELECT Id, ActivityDate, Subject FROM ActivityHistories ORDER BY ActivityDate desc NULLS LAST) FROM Account where id = '0012000001XIdCt'
```

Each time I run this I'm getting a `NotFound` error back but if I run this within the developer console it works perfectly. Is there limitations of this on the REST side?!

I also come across this post on the dev forums;

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BKf0IAG

I can see he has the ActivityHistories within his describe of the object but I can't seem to get this either.

Anyone tried this at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running against the REST API try structuring your GET as follows:

```
/services/data/v34.0/query?q=SELECT (SELECT Id, ActivityDate, Subject FROM ActivityHistories ORDER BY ActivityDate desc NULLS LAST) FROM Account where id = '0012000001XIdCt'
```

Also, if you want to test against the REST API, one excellent resource I use all the time is the developer workbench which can be found here : https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php

Comment: Just realised I was querying v36 of the api which I don't think actually exists  just yet. Will mark as answer, thanks.